# htaccess order Deny,Allow rule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'd like to dynamically add IPs to a block list via htaccess. I was hoping someone could tell me if the following will work in my case (I'm unsure how to test via localhost).

My .htaccess file will have the following by default:

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

IPs will be dynamically appended:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

The way I understand this is that it is by default allow all with the optional list of deny rules. If I'm not mistaken `Order Deny,Allow` will look at the Deny list first, is this correct?

And does the Allow from all rule need to be at the end?

**EDIT 1**

If I'm not mistaken I need to do this based on jeffatrackaid's answer:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

**EDIT 2**

For the sake of completeness, this is probably more appropriate for my requirements:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This rule allows everyone into your site.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

The `Order` directive determines the order in which your rules are processed. With `Order deny,allow` the deny list will be processed first then the allow list.

With Apache, all rules are processed with the last one matching being the effective rule.

So in this case, your last rule would be `allow from all`.

This means that `192.168.30.1` would initially be denied but then allowed since the allow rules are processed last.

This would produce the same result

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Deny from 192.168.30.1
Allow from 192.168.30.1
```

Think of it this way.

- The allow/deny rules are simply separate lists of IPs to be allowed/denied.
- The `order` directive determines the order in which these lists are
  processed.
- Apache evaluates all rules and acts on the result of the
  last matching rule.

The major confusion is that this is very different from how firewalls work where rule order and first match is often what determines access.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order

Comment: Thnaks for the detailed explanation.  I was under the impression that 'deny, allow' will always apply the deny rule, even on subsequent attempts. Any recommendations on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your updated code `allow,deny` should work. The allow list is processed first followed by the deny list.  So if an IP is listed in the deny list it will be blocked since it will be last matched.  Just one note, if you have too many deny rules you may see performance issues.  All rules are processed on every request.  "Too many" depends on your hardware and server loads but something to keep in mind with any tool that auto-adds rules to .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration file, e.g., .conf, if you have:

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Allow from all 
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

The user wanted to block the access to only one IP, 192.168.30.1, but allowing access to the rest.

**Reality**: Apache grants access to all IP address, exposing a severe security threat and is entirely opposite of the user’s intent.

**Root Cause**: the entry `Order` plays the key role: it decides the order in which the functions deny and allow are executed. If the value of `Order` is set to `deny,allow`, any IP address matching the value specified in the entry `Deny from` gets a temporary return value deny. After that it is checking the entry `Allow from`, and if it matches, it receives the return value allow, that overwrites the previous value.
 
Looking at the source code snippet in Apache (see below), you can find that
why 192.168.30.1 is not blocked by Apache.

```c
int ret = OK; // default 
if (a->order[method]==ALLOW_THEN_DENY) { 
    ret = HTTP_FORBIDDEN;   
    if (find_allowdeny(r,a-> allows,method)) 
        ret = OK;   
    if (find_allowdeny(r,a-> denys,method)) 
        ret = HTTP_FORBIDDEN;}
 else if (a->order[method]== DENY_THEN_ALLOW) { 
    if (find_allowdeny(r,a-> denys,method)) 
        ret = HTTP_FORBIDDEN; 
    if (find_allowdeny(r,a-> allows,method)) 
        ret = OK;} 
else    
   { if (find_allowdeny(r,a-> allows,method) && !find_allowdeny(r,a-> denys,method)) 
    ret = OK; 
else    
    ret = HTTP_FORBIDDEN;}
```

The correct version of this configuration would be:

```
Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```

or just a single line of

```
Deny from 192.168.30.1
```